# Recover and continue for loop if panic occur Golang

Tags: for-loop, go, panic

so my case is quite complex but for asking question in clean and clear context I am using simple for loop that initiate from 0 and goes upto 10. Now what I am trying to do is when `i becomes equal to 2` program will consider this as panic. It will go to recover state using defer and then after recovery loop will resume.

So desired output should be something like that:

```
0
1
panic occured: got 2
3
4
.
.
.
.
.
10
```

Actual output I am getting

```
0
1
panic occured got:  got 2
```

Code block:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    goFrom1To10()
}

func goFrom1To10() {
    defer recovery()
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {

        if i == 2 {
            panic("got 2")

        }
        fmt.Println(i)
    }

}

func recovery() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        fmt.Println("panic occured: ", r)
    }

}
```

Can this be achievable in go like when panic occur somehow we can recover and complete our loop?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do that if the body of the loop is executed as a function, either anonymous or a named one, and in that function you use a deferred function to recover.

Here's how it looks like with anonymous functions:

```
func goFrom1To10() {
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        func() {
            defer func() {
                if r := recover(); r != nil {
                    fmt.Println("panic occured: ", r)
                }
            }()

            if i == 2 {
                panic("got 2")
            }
            fmt.Println(i)
        }()
    }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ii77rO3VHlY)):

```
0
1
panic occured:  got 2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

It's nicer and easier to understand if you move it to a named function:

```
func goFrom1To10() {
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        task(i)
    }
}

func task(i int) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("panic occured: ", r)
        }
    }()

    if i == 2 {
        panic("got 2")
    }
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NVOTA2z_XIs).

Comment: thanks @icza for your answer and explanation, your logic and solution help me such cases create separate function for panic and recovery.  Again thanks!

Comment: @icza, I could not understand the logic behind it. Please can you explain , why it's happening by shifting recovery calls near to panic or something like this. ?

Comment: And I can use `continue` within this function to directly go to the next loop iteration, right?

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś You can't, which you can easily try and get a compile-time error. But returning from the function has the same effect as `continue` inside the loop.